# Struts 1.x application - Page Unavailable

Tags: apache-poi, struts, struts-1

I have a struts 1.x web application and trying to click on action link on JSP page, the action performs a database call and creating an Excel sheet out of resultset. 
The smaller result set has no issues but bigger resultset, exactly after 5 minutes the application displays with "Page Unavailable" and no error logs on server.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Apache POI API using for exception generation.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided.

Comment: Can you show the action called?